# Прочитать Excel файл в C#

Tags: c#, excel

Мне нужно прочитать файл Excel. 
Все примеры, которые я нашел, либо не работают, либо слишком сложные для понимания, как для новичка.

Как открыть файл в загнать данные в `DataGridView`?

Answer (score 3):

Вот такая же [тема](http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread44307.html?uri=/csharp-net/thread44307.html), ещё один пример: [Import Excel File to DataSet](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32370/Import-Excel-File-to-DataSet).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection MyConnection;
    DataSet DtSet;
    OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;

    MyConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\fileExcel.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
    MyCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection);
    MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net");
    DtSet = new DataSet();
    MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
    MyConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Возникла ошибка: Внешняя таблица не имеет предполагаемый формат.

Comment: У меня все работает. 
(Win7, Excel 2010. Книга сохранена в формате 97-2003 (*.xls))
Мож название таблицы не Sheet1 у тебя.

Comment: Теперь другая ошибка: Объект 'rem$' не найден ядром базы данных Microsoft Jet.  Проверьте существование объекта и правильность имени и пути.

Вот файл: http://rghost.net/41461981

Подскажите что не так.

Comment: Работает с твоим файлом 
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/37689745/WindowsFormsApplication1.7z
(студия 2012)

Answer (score 1):

Работайте через схему источника данных.
Кидаю этот участок из рабочего кода проекта:

```
DataTable COL = null;

DataTable dtSchema = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { });
DataTable columns = null;
foreach (DataRow row in dtSchema.Rows)
{
...
COL = con.GetSchema("Columns", restrictions); //колонки
...
}
```

и пошло поехало
можно описать select какой-то, потом его использовать, например:
(инициализацию этих я опустил)

```
adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(select, strConnection);
dtExcel = new DataTable("Excel_Table");
```

удачи!

Есть нюанс - какую версию Экселя парсите (по умолчанию, идет 8 версия, парсится без проблем. С ранними версиями, может быть, ошибки будут)